# Adding CustomUI Ribbon using Shared Add-in(not VSTO) in Outlook 2007,2010,2013

Tags: outlook, c#-2.0, outlook-addin, ribbon, shared-addin

I am using VS 2010 and my project template is Extensibility->Shared Add-in. I want an ribbon with a button which should invoke my form in outlook. I am not able to understand how to do this?

I created a ribbonName.xml and ribbionName.cs using office template Outlook2007 Add-in and add this two files in my Shared Add-in Am I doing it right or What should i do ?

Please can anyone guide me a how to do it ?

Where should i add this method in Connect Or ? when i add this in Connect It gives me error "no sutiable method to overload"

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()  {
     return new TurboAddinsRibbon();
  }
```

Can anyone please give me a simple example on this it would be great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start from the [MSDN Reference - Ribbon Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386097%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the [RibbonManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonfactory.createribbonmanager.aspx) and the [BackStage view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff936212%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to get started.

Comment: Thank you for links i was able to create the ribbons in 2007,2010,2013. I want to ask you one question i want to create a ribbon using a separate class library referencing to my com Add-in.

Comment: @C_J, you may try to extend the `Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility` namespace - Check the Creating the Add-Ins Tab section on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa942955.aspx) or [Customize the Ribbon](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010211415.aspx).

Comment: @C_J, you may even like to refer to the [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.aspx) and check the [Ribbon Manager Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonmanager.aspx), [Ribbon Factory Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonfactory.aspx) and [IRibbonExtension Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.iribbonextension.aspx).

Comment: I have extended the Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility to my class library class. I have created customUI.xml and added it in my Resource.resx file and gave the reference of this class in my actual com-addin.Now i am calling the class library in my OnStartUpComplete of my com-addin but it is not getting invoked.Please can you suggest something.